# How to calculate the standard deviation for the "final weighted mean difference" as in a meta-analysis for the purpose of calculating sample size?

Tags: sample-size

I am seeing a Forest Plot presentation of the data in a meta-analysis. But the standard deviation for the final "weighted mean difference" is missing. I am wondering if it is possible to calculate the standard deviation of it. So that I can use this SD value in G power to estimate the sample size.

The meta-analysis paper title: Efficacy of combination therapy with ezetimibe and statins versus a double dose of statin monotherapy in participants with hypercholesterolemia: a meta-analysis of literature

I need to find the standard deviation to estimate a sample size for a retrospective research that I am about to conduct.